# How can ignore a string in quotes in this regex match?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How can I ignore instances of the string "or" when it is inside single/double quotes?

The current expression is `/^(?=\$)(.+?)(?:\s+or\s+)(.+?)$/s`

Test value 1: `$test or "default value"`

Test value 2: `$errors->has('email') ? 'error or failure' : ''`

Test value 1 should be affected, but value 2 should be unaffected.

**Test script:**

Update `$expression` to test.

```php
<?php

function issetDefaults($value) {

    // Original expression with the issue
    //$expression = '/^(?=\$)(.+?)(?:\s+or\s+)(.+?)$/s';

    // @Avinash Raj's version; almost there; failing on test 2
    $expression = '/([\'"])(?:(?!\1).)*or(?:(?!\1).)*\1(*SKIP)(*F)|^(\S+) or ([\'"].*[\'"])/';
    return preg_replace($expression, 'isset($2) ? $2 : $3', $value);
}

// Tests
$tests = array(

    // should be affected
    '$test or "default value"',
    '$age or 90',

    // shouldn't be affected
    'myfunc(\'foo or bar\')',
    '$errors->has(\'email\') ? \'error or failure\' : \'\'',
    '$errors->has("email") ? "error or failure" : ""',
    '$errors->has("email") ? "error \'or\' failure" : ""'
);


// Output tests
foreach ($tests as $key => $test) {
    $num = $key+1;
    echo '<strong>Original Value '.$num.'</strong>';
    echo '<pre>'.print_r($test,true).'</pre>';

    echo '<strong>Value '.$num.' after function</strong>';
    echo '<pre>'.print_r(issetDefaults($test),true).'</pre>';

    echo '<hr />';
}
```

Comment: Give a sample input and expected output.

Comment: You mean ignoring `"or"` or `"cake or bread"`?

Comment: @Unihedron — It matches something like `$example or 'default value'` and if it matches, it will replace the whole thing with `isset($example) ? $example : 'default value'`. I don't want it to match something like `$example = "this or that"`.

Comment: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below regex would matches the string `or` which was not enclosed within single or double quotes,

```
(['"])(?:(?!\1).)*or(?:(?!\1).)*\1(*SKIP)(*F)|\bor\b
```

Replace `or` with whatever string you want.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pV9qT4/6)

**Explanation:**

- `(['"])` Captures `'` or `"` symbols.
- `(?:(?!\1).)*` Matches any character not the one which was captured into the first group zero or more times.
- `or` Matches the string `or`.
- `(?:(?!\1).)*` Matches any character not the one which was captured into the first group zero or more times.
- `\1` First captured group was referred through back referencing.
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` Makes the whole match to fail and the characters which are following `|` symbol(`\bor\b`) would be matched from the remaining part.

Comment: This matches correctly, but not in the context of the above script. For a match, I need the groups for the replace statement.

Comment: @DesignerGuy in this `$test or "default value"`, what do you want to capture?

Comment: Both `$test` and `"default value"` should be captured as `$1` and `$2` respectively.

Comment: see http://regex101.com/r/pV9qT4/7 and see http://regex101.com/r/pV9qT4/8 to capture single quotes also

Comment: How can I include the quotes with the default value string? Right now group 2 returns `default value` when it should return `"default value"`.

Comment: see the second link, let me know whether it works or not. See this also http://regex101.com/r/pV9qT4/9

Comment: +1 for `(*SKIP)(*F)`. I hope your answer gets a green check mark. :)

Comment: It actually breaks on one case: `myfunc('foo or bar')` — see http://regex101.com/r/pV9qT4/10

Comment: it just skips the `'foo or bar'` part . Did you want the whole line to be skipped then try this http://regex101.com/r/pV9qT4/11 and this http://regex101.com/r/pV9qT4/12

Comment: Oops. Actually, this one: regex101.com/r/pV9qT4/9 is almost there. I wanted to match with or without quotes though. `$age or 90` should match. I updated my test cases up in the script above.

Comment: Back to the other issue. Here's a link with the proper test cases listed: http://regex101.com/r/pV9qT4/15

Comment: You, sir, are a regex champion! Thanks!